# ESP8266 to ESP32

Tags: esp8266, esp32

A fairly new coder here so please be patient.

I am working on porting some code that creates an LED display from ESP8266 to ESP32.

In the header file I have noted the ESP8266 statements and have simply added an additional #elif statement as shown below. However this does not work as the ESP32 does not appear to control ports in the same way as the ESP8266

So the compile fails.

I have done a bit of research on this but its all a bit off the mark. I have found the ESP8266 header which contains GPOS and GPOC and it looks like this:

#define GPOS   ESP8266_REG(0x304) //GPIO_OUT_SET WO

#define GPOC   ESP8266_REG(0x308) //GPIO_OUT_CLR WO

So I am looking for some pointers to getting the equivalent to GPOC / GPOS in the ESP32 framework. I know this may not result in the scheme working but it moves things forward a bit.

Thanks.

Sample showing my change - does not work

*#if defined (ESP8266)

#define DOUT_HIGH GPOS = 1<<4

#define DOUT_LOW GPOC = 1<<4*

#elif defined (ESP32) // MY ADDITION

#define DOUT_HIGH GPOS = 1<<4

#define DOUT_LOW GPOC = 1<<4

Comment: I have googled that, and all sorts of variations - and after several different avenues of investigation without result, it led me here.

Comment: Does [Direct IO Port Manipulation](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=1746) have the information you're looking for?

Comment: I have spent a bit of time looking at that yesterday and today - frankly I am not sure if it does - but it seems to be going in the right direction.

Comment: "So the compile fails". What exactly the error message? My guess is that `ESP8266` is defined somewhere, but `ESP32` is not. So I think you should change `#elif defined(ESP32)` to simply `#else`.

Comment: More reliable way of doing it is `#if defined ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 .... #elif defined ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32` because those constants are set at each board definition level.

Comment: Thanks guys. The error was that the GPOC and GPOS definitions do not exist. This I understood as they are unique to the 8266 header file and not available when this header is not used. I tried using the REG_WRITE ( GPIO_OUT_W1TS_REG, BIT2 )  macro as this appear to work for the ESP32 based on an example elsewhere but although this succeeded in getting some LEDs to turn on, the sequencing and control was lost. I believe that there are other issues with the porting to ESP32 which I do not understand and likely to prove even more troublesome to correct.  So I have given up on this for now.